# Symfony Doctrine or Query Builder exclude tabdle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have project with
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.6.11",
and when I open page all entity(in my situation developer) I use standart doctrine fincrion

```
$all_developer = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Developer')->findAll();

    public function findAll()
{
    return $this->findBy(array(), array('id' => 'ASC'));
}
```

I wait 4 minutes open page and in debug panel I see download 103mb o_O this is nearly 4000 entity

I install DebeshaDoctrineProfileExtraBundle and I see with my entity developer I load table TalentFiles in this table I have file doc docx pdf how to disable this table when I find all develoeprs?

```
1   10.54 ms    1   SimpleObjectHydrator    

r => Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Users

2   63.57 ms    100     ObjectHydrator  

r => Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Developer
e0 => Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\TalentFiles
```

I visible for you only field with relationship because I think maybe this is problem for download, when I find Developer doctrine find al entity in relationship. How to exclude all relationship and find all entity without this fields (who have realationship) If use Query Builder how to exclude??? Or how to exclude in DOCTRINE another table??

```
    public function getDevelopers()
{

    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('d');

    $qb
        ->select('d')
        ->from('ArtelProfileBundle:Developer', 'd')
        //how to exclude???

        ->getQuery();
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->getResult();

    return $results;
}
```

Entity Developers and relationship

```
/**
 * Developers
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="developers")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\DeveloperRepository")
 */
 class Developer extends CustomUser
 {
///////////other field, I visible for you only field with relation ship

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="TalentFiles", mappedBy="developer", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $talent_file;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CodeUserReference", mappedBy="developer", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
protected $reference_developer;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CodeProjectNotificationLater", mappedBy="developer", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
public $notification_later;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Teams", inversedBy="developers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="team_id", nullable = true, referencedColumnName="id")
 * */
protected $teams;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CodeTalentsProjects", mappedBy="authorId", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $projects;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comments", mappedBy="talent", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
public $comment;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Users", inversedBy="add_developer")
 */
protected $added_by;
```

And some interesting - when I open home page with first page, this page have routing in another action and some information for entity admin thats all, without any entity I wait 15 - 40 second ans download 15-28mb o_0

In frontend I use metronic admin bundle maybe this information help

I add some screen in debug panel maybe this help for diagnostic problem
[link](http://uploads.ru/lDIau.png),[link](http://uploads.ru/JQArn.png),[link](http://uploads.ru/AROPz.png),[link](http://uploads.ru/ydx2P.png).Help please, maybe some people have this problem ??

Comment: Are you explicitly accesing talent_file property? Because, in doctrine, the association are marked, by default, as LAZY, so them shouldn't be loaded (as you want)

Comment: when I debug I see array developers in one developer I see all entity relationship OneToMany and I not understand how this affects the load and how exclude this entity  ?

Comment: If your debug calls or "goes deep" into relationship then you'll see them hydrated (loaded) but, trust me, if you fetch an entity and you don't call the relation attribute, no more objects are loaded from db

Comment: ok I trust you, but why with help in DebeshaDoctrineProfileExtraBundle and I see with my entity developer I load table TalentFiles - OneToOne? In this table I have Cv people doc docx and pdf and maybe this is reason 103mb. How to exclude this table?

Comment: Again, if you don't use it you will not run into any problem of this type, maybe your memory consumption is elsewhere. If you use them, you can try with extra lazy fetch (search for it, I'm from mobile now) or you can use doctrine iterators

Comment: ok, why I have many time in controller http://uploads.ru/AROPz.png ?Maybe if you have time and PC maybe you give little example extra lazy?

Comment: Can we see corresponding action that cause you that time wait?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88688/discussion-between-shuba-ivan-and-doncallisto).